# Issues installing apache httpd 2.4.20 with ldap

Tags: apache, unix, ldap

I am trying to configure apache using the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/nms/app/apache --with-apr=/home/kvanapal/httpd-2.4.20/srclib/apr --with-apr-util=/home/kvanapal/httpd-2.4.20/srclib/apr-util/apu--config --enable-mods-shared=all --with-ldap --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util --enable-ldap
```

After this I am running the make command and this gives the following error towards the end:

> ```
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x3f0): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_url_parse'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x3f8): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_url_parse_ext'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x400): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_is_ldapi_url'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x408): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_is_ldaps_url'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x410): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_is_ldap_url'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x418): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_rebind_remove'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x420): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_rebind_add'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x428): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_rebind_init'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x430): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_set_option'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x438): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_get_option'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x440): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_info'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x448): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_init'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x450): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_ssl_deinit'
> server/.libs/libmain.a(exports.o):(.data+0x458): undefined reference to `apr_ldap_ssl_init'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1
> ```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: I am also getting this issue and found no resolution yet.